# Dalvikvm Unable to resolve direct/virtual method

Tags: android, cordova, dalvik

Last week I upgraded from Cordova 2.6.0 to 2.9.0. Ever since I'm getting dalvik errors that I can't seem to get rid of, no matter what I try. It doesn't crash my app, however, I'm not able to use the File API anymore. I'm testing my app in Android 2.2, my minSDK is 8, my targetSDK is 17 and I'm building against 17 too. Here is the logcat:

```
09-02 13:48:00.148: D/JsMessageQueue(1037): Set native->JS mode to 2
09-02 13:48:00.148: I/CordovaWebView(1037): Disabled addJavascriptInterface() bridge since Android version is old.
09-02 13:48:00.148: E/dalvikvm(1037): Could not find class 'android.webkit.WebResourceResponse', referenced from method org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.getWhitelistResponse
09-02 13:48:00.148: W/dalvikvm(1037): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 130 (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;) in Lorg/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient;
09-02 13:48:00.158: W/dalvikvm(1037): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;)
09-02 13:48:00.158: W/dalvikvm(1037): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;)
09-02 13:48:00.158: W/dalvikvm(1037): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;)
09-02 13:48:00.158: D/DroidGap(1037): DroidGap.init()
09-02 13:48:00.168: D/CordovaWebView(1037): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
09-02 13:48:00.168: D/PluginManager(1037): init()
09-02 13:48:00.178: D/CordovaWebView(1037): >>> loadUrlNow()
```

Anyone know a solution to this weird problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the docs for the missing method, [android.webkit.WebResourceResponse](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebResourceResponse.html) was added in API 11 (Android 3.0).  It appears that `org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient` is attempting to use a class that doesn't exist in Android 2.2.

This is not necessarily fatal.  It's not uncommon for libraries to include code that references classes that didn't exist on older versions of the platform.  At runtime they detect the platform version and don't actually use those classes.

So you should ignore the Dalvik verifier complaints.  Look for any failure messages at the point where the File API is used.